# While updating, mongoose is giving me an error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'vidName' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update one particular field in the document. Here is my code:

```
module.exports.editAndUpdate = function(playerVideo, callback) {
    console.log(playerVideo.vidName);
    var newVidId = toString(playerVideo.vidId);
    myModel.findById(newVidId, function(err, doc) {
      if(err) throw err;
      doc.vidName = playerVideo.vidName;
      doc.save(callback);
    });
 }
```

Here `playerVideo` is a document, `vidName` and `vidId` are its fields.

Instead of `doc.vidName = playerVideo.vidName`, if I use `doc.vidName = "Hey"`, then it is working perfectly fine. I used the `typeof` method and checked if `playerVideo.vidName` is a `String` and yes, it is.

Please help me solve this. Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: The error says that playerVideo is `null`, did you try to log it inside the `findById` callback ?

Comment: Try to console your doc i think it is null. Check that you are finding the result correctly.

Comment: From where you are calling `editAndUpdate` fucntion? And what you are passing as the first parameter of that function? Check you are not passing null value while calling `editAndUpdate`.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for the suggestions. @boehm_s, @Mariya James, @titi23, I did what you guys have suggested. I have 1) logged `playerVideo`,2) checked if the doc is null in the mongo console, 3) checked if I have passed a null parameter. All the above were not null. But `newVidId` turned out to be null. I have used the `toString()` method in a wrong way. It should have been `playerVideo.vidId.toString()`. `newVidId` being null, did not help in finding a doc. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue occurred when I was updating a nested object, which had a fullstop in the key value.

e.g.

```js
"$set": {
    "some.field": {
        "validuser": "this works",
        "invalid.user": "this breaks mongo"
    }
}
```

MongoDB [doesn't support keys with a dot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names), and was providing this cryptic error:

> cannot set property 'value' of null

Solution - don't store keys with a fullstop in it!